# python pandas add list in dataframe column as default value

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to make a new column in dataframe df that will fill all rows with `[np.nan]`

```
    df['new'] = [np.nan]
```

I get

```
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

If I try

```
    test['new'] = np.nan
    test['new'] = test['new'].astype('object')
    test['new'] = [np.nan]
```

I get

```
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

I'd like to be sure that all rows are filled with a list containing `nan`

Comment: Hold on , you want np.nan in each cell or [np.nan] ?

Comment: Each cell yes, that's correct.

Comment: Why would you want `[np.nan]` instead of `np.nan`? That's inefficient and highly inadvisable. Your series will become `object` type (a sequence of pointers) rather than `float`.

Comment: Because it will be loaded into a Postgresql table that has a column of array type: bigint[]. It has to match data type

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are assign a `object`

```
df['New']=[[np.nan]]*len(df)
df
Out[250]: 
        Date  Value    New
0 2017-01-01      1  [nan]
1 2017-02-13      2  [nan]
2 2018-03-01      3  [nan]
3 2018-04-01      4  [nan]
```